# Ruby Enumerable: get the first which is not nil, but the result must be what's inside the block

Tags: ruby, enumerable

The `Enumerable#find` method works by evaluating until the it finds an element which matches the condition in the block. Is there something similar for returning the first time that the block is not evaluated to nil? imagining one would have a collection of hashes:

```
value = nil
options.each do |o|                     
  break if value = o[:desired]
end                                     
value ||= DEFAULT
```

isn't there a method which already accomplishes this?

No point in making a lot of transformations to the collection, i'd like to minimize the number of allocations, so any solution which allocates a new Array will not be good for me.

Comment: Not sure if that is what you re asking but doesn't just negating the `nil?` check do your bidding?

Answer (score 3):

`find` method will work for finding first element which has `:desired` key with minimum iterations.

I think you wish to get the value of `desired` key from the block instead of element itself - there is no method in `Enumerable` that behaves like a mixture of `find` and `map`  - you will have to use the outer variable to which value is assigned inside the block as shown below.

```
options = [{foo: 1}, {desired: 2}, {bar: 3}]

value = nil
options.find do |o|
  value = o[:desired]
  break if value
end

p value
#=> 2
```

It more or less looks like your code, which should also work just fine.

Below is one way which you can use if you want to use `Enumerable` methods, but it will iterate over all elements.

```
p value = options.map { |o| value = o[:desired] }.compact.first
```

Comment: I think he wants method to find first that has `:desired` key

Comment: @SteveTurczyn  I understood what he is asking now - thanks for pointing out the flaw with my earlier answer.

Answer (score 1):

As of Ruby 2.0, this can be accomplished by combining `#map` and `#find` with [lazy enumerables](https://railsware.com/blog/2012/03/13/ruby-2-0-enumerablelazy/):

```
value = options.lazy.map { |o| o[:desired] }.find { |x| !x.nil? } # or find(&:present?) with ActiveSupport
value ||= DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce):

```
value = options.reduce(nil){|memo, entry|  memo || entry[:desired]  } || DEFAULT
```

Comment: won't it parse the options collection until the end? this is what I wanted to avoid. `#find` will stop evaluation as soon as it has a match.

Comment: Correct, it's possible to break with a value though - see my answer 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/57630623/2993768

Answer (score 0):

This came up for me today: I think we can use break with a value from reduce

```
treasure = [1,2,3].reduce(nil) do |memo, value|
  break memo if memo
  foo(value)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
options.reduce{ |_,o|
   break o if o[:desired]
   DEFAULT
}
```

or

```
catch do |tag|
   options.each{ |_,o| o[:desired] and throw tag, o }
   DEFAULT
end
```

The latter allows for recursion.

Comment: Would you mind editing your answer to include a brief explanation of how this differs from the previous existing answers?